# Loop not printing correct results on view

Tags: javascript, vue.js, methods, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I'm trying make my Coordinates, Dispatcher and Captured At printout the correct totals that correspond to it's ID. Unfortunately, it's only assigning the first ID's totals in its HTML element. Having a bit of a braindead moment trying to fix this.

I know I'm missing something to identify the individual html instance, but I can't figure out how to make that happen.

HTML -

```
<div v-if="zoomLevel > 10" class="search-data">
  <div><strong>Dispatcher:</strong>&nbsp;<span id="dispatcher">{{ dispatcher}}</span></div>
  <div><strong>Lng/Lat:</strong>&nbsp;<span id="coordinates">{{ coordinates }}</span></div>
  <div><strong>Captured At:</strong>&nbsp;<span id="capturedAt">{{ capturedAt }}</span></div>
</div>
```

JS -

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      coordinates: '',
      dispatcher: '',
      capturedAt: '',
    }
  },
}
```

Method -

```
let totalTargets = Object.keys(e.source.data.features).length;
for (let i = 0; i < totalTargets; i++) {
  console.log(e)
  this.coordinates = e.source.data.features[i].geometry.coordinates.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]"," ").replace(",", ", ");
  this.dispatcher = e.source.data.features[i].properties.name;
  this.capturedAt = e.source.data.features[i].properties.capturedAt;
}
```

Console.log printout of method results

[image]

Comment: How is the shape of your data looking? Do you have what you're looping on?

Comment: The data itself is fine, it just assigns the first set of coordinates in the returned array object to every instance of this.coordinates

Comment: Maybe I am missing what you are trying to accomplish, but it looks like you are overwriting coordinates, dispatcher, and capturedAt in your loop. If you want store them all in reactive data, you need to coordinates, dispather and capturedAt and array and then push to them. Then in your template, use v-for to loop through each one. Or another option would be to store data.features as reactive data and loop through that in your template directly instead of splitting them up at first.

Comment: @rguttersohn I thought of doing the first one, but couldn't seem to make it work. I assume I wrote it up wrong. What I'm doing sounds closer to your second idea, but how do I loop through the reactive data and not split them up?

Comment: got it. Yeah just make those three data points an array and then this.dispatcher.push(this.dispatcher = e.source.data.features[i].properties.name;) and then the same for the other two. If this is data retrieved asynchronously based on user input, you'll need to remember to empty each array before the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate on the HTML, with v-for, create a reactive property to your list and can use like this:

```
<div v-if="zoomLevel > 10" class="search-data" v-for="(feature, index) in features" :key="index">
    <div><strong>Dispatcher:</strong>&nbsp;<span id="dispatcher">{{ feature.dispatcher}}</span></div>
    <div><strong>Lng/Lat:</strong>&nbsp;<span id="coordinates">{{ feature.coordinates }}</span></div>
    <div><strong>Captured At:</strong>&nbsp;<span id="capturedAt">{{ feature.capturedAt }}</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That makes sense, but where does `features` in the v-for come from? I assume that's a features array i need to create in the `export default.data`

Comment: If I understood your code, the for you're using get the feature from some call. So you create a **const features = reactive({ data: {} })** and where you create a for you set this variable **feature.data = e.source.data.features**

Comment: @AlexandreHeinen, I believe the OP is using the Options API, not Composition.

Comment: In this case just create the list variable and return it on **data** and then set the **e.source.data.features** when it necessary